# Using jQuery attr() to set “css”

Tags: jquery, css, attr

I am reading the book "jQuery Pocket Reference", O’Reilly, 2011.

On page 15 it says:

'For example, calling attr("css", {backgroundColor:"gray"}) is the same as calling css({backgroundColor:"gray"}).'

But I cannot make the attr(“css”, { }) work.  My test code: http://jsfiddle.net/4UMN3/4/

```
$(function() {
$("#btnChangeColor").click(function () {
$("#spanText").attr("css", { backgroundColor: "gray" });

 });

});
```

The css() method works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/4UMN3/5/

Comment: Nothing about it in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Might be an [error in the book](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920016182).

Comment: Why would you need to use `.attr()` if you have `.css()`?

Comment: Does this correspond to the [second confirmed error on O'Reilly's site](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920016182)?

Comment: Yes, the css() works fine. It's just because I am reading this book.
In develop tool, I found css="[object Object]" was added to the span. It seems that the attr() cannot recognize the “css” attribute.
<span css="[object Object]" id="spanText" style="background-color: red">This is a test</span>

Comment: @Blazemonger - Good find, that's the one. Author goofed.

Comment: Yup, the book is definitely wrong

Comment: The attribute is not css but style, but, in fact, this is not the same thing that using css(). If you read it in a book, this is a mistake.

Comment: @j08691 to be sure, the author also submitted the correction. :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Replace:

```
$("#spanText").attr("css", { backgroundColor: "gray" });
```

with

```
$("#spanText").attr('style',  'background-color:gray');
```

Answer (score 9):

Probably, it was meant to be

```
$("#spanText").attr('style', 'background-color:gray');
```

This may work, but has some problems:

- It is preferred to change `style` property instead of `style` attribute.
- It will replace all previously set inline styles.

Then, if you use jQuery, better use `css` method:

```
$("#spanText").css('background-color', 'gray');
```

But `style` property is useful in vanilla-js:

```
document.getElementById("spanText").style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
```

Answer (score 3):

I think jQuery's .attr() can only affect attributes the element has.
HTMLElements do not know an attribute called "css" (meaning `<div css="something"></div>`).

So, the correct usage would be

```
$("#spanText").attr("style",{backgroundColor:"gray"});
```

But this outputs

```
<span id="spanText" style="[object Object]">This is a test</span>
```

An example that actually works is

```
$("#spanText").attr("style","background-color:gray;");
```

Comment: The `.css()` function understands the object literal syntax, the `.attr()` method doesn't.

Comment: I never claimed something different. I just wanted to show why the shown syntax does not work.

Comment: I was just commenting for the benefit of any reader - not criticising your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#id").attr('style',  'color:red;cursor:pointer');
```

Answer (score 0):

=> the .css method modifies the style attribute not the "css" .

```
$().att('style' , 'backgroundColor : gray');
```

=> there is no such thing as css attribute in html

Answer (score 0):

you use jQuery so you have to use **css** and not **attr**, 'cause **css** add ***property*** but **attr** will replace all *style* if existe !

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .newClass{
    color:#fff;
    }
    .test2{
    color:red;
    }
    .newclass{
    color:blue;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //get style and class name in alert
      $('#attr').click(function () {
        alert($('h3').attr("style"));
        alert($('h3').attr("class"));
      });

     //set css property
     $("#setcss").click(function(){
        $("#test").css({"background-color": "#000", "color": "teal"});
      });

      //change class name property
      $('#changeclassname').click(function(){
        $('#test3').removeClass('test2').addClass('newclass');
      });
});


</script>


<!--get style and class name in alert-->
<h3 class="test" style="color: white; background: red;">This is the tag and this will be our tag</h3> 

<button id="attr">get Attribute</button>


<!--set css property-->
<p id="test" class="test1">This is some <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.</p>

<button id="setcss">set Attribute</button>


<!--change class name property-->
<p id="test3" class="test2">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>

<button id="changeclassname">set Attribute</button>
```